# TabLayout Scroll and RecyclerView Scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I'm using a **tabLayout** with a **horizontal recyclerView**

The problem is when I scroll the recyclerView, the tabLayout takes priority instead of RecyclerView.

This only happens when the tabLayout is in the last tab, the tabLayout has no more scrolling.

TabLayout have this attributes

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextStyle"
            >
```

And I setted the recyclerView with the attribute setHasFixedSize

```
recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

> This gif shows the problem.

[image: Problem with the recycler and tabs]

> Here works well, because the tabLayout is not in the last tab.

[image: This works well]

Comment: Did you try setnestedscrollingenabled(false) on your recyclerview

Comment: Yes, I tried that and doesn't change anything. Still not work.

Comment: Anyone? I still have the problem...

The recyclerView is inside a ScrollView and the scrollview is inside a viewPager. I used SetNestedScrollingEnabled(false) but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide complete code so I can't say where are you committing the mistake. But hope below lines can help you

```
     LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

After that, if you will swipe from right most side to left then tab will change in between of recyclerview also.